# Drawing over another drawing in HTML Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So, in my car-parking based webgame, I want it so the car goes over the parking lines in the html canvas, but nothing is working. Obviously, I tried putting the car drawing in javascript before the parking lot, but that doesn't work. I have the game at https://parkingmaster.w3spaces.com try parking over the lines, they'll go over the car.

JavaScript:

```
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      last = performance.now(),
      x = 0,
      animate;
var y = 20;
function draw() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(x, y, 110,65);
      ctx.rect(x + 5, y + 58, 30,10);
      ctx.rect(x + 75, y + 58, 30,10)
      ctx.rect(x + 5, y - 3, 30,10);
      ctx.rect(x + 75, y -3, 30,10)
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
      ctx.fill();
      x += 5;
      animate = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
if (x > 500) {
GameOver();
}
parkinglot(draw);
document.getElementById("speedbar").innerHTML = '5';
};

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      last = performance.now(),
      x = 0,
      animate;
var y = 20;
 function mouseRightDown(draw) {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(x, y, 110,65);
      ctx.rect(x + 5, y + 58, 30,10);
      ctx.rect(x + 75, y + 58, 30,10)
      ctx.rect(x + 5, y - 3, 30,10);
      ctx.rect(x + 75, y -3, 30,10)
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
      ctx.fill();
      y += 1.5;
      x += 0.3;
if (y > canvas.height - 66) {
GameOver();
}
      animate2 = requestAnimationFrame(mouseRightDown);
parkinglot(draw);
}
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      last = performance.now(),
      x = 0,
      animate;
var y = 20;
 function mouseLeftDown(draw) {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(x, y, 110,65);
      ctx.rect(x + 5, y + 58, 30,10);
      ctx.rect(x + 75, y + 58, 30,10)
      ctx.rect(x + 5, y - 3, 30,10);
      ctx.rect(x + 75, y -3, 30,10)
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
      ctx.fill();
      y += -1.5;
      x += 0.3;
if (y < -1) {
GameOver();
}
      animate3 = requestAnimationFrame(mouseLeftDown);
parkinglot(draw);
}
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      last = performance.now(),
      x = 0,
      animate;
var y = 20;
 function mouseReverseDown(draw) {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(x, y, 110,65);
      ctx.rect(x + 5, y + 58, 30,10);
      ctx.rect(x + 75, y + 58, 30,10)
      ctx.rect(x + 5, y - 3, 30,10);
      ctx.rect(x + 75, y -3, 30,10)
      ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
      ctx.fill();
      x += -4;
if (x < -2) {
GameOver();
}
document.getElementById("speedbar").innerHTML = '4';
      animate4 = requestAnimationFrame(mouseReverseDown);
parkinglot(draw);
}
function GameOver() {
var gameOverAlert = alert("Game Over");
var gameOverAlert = false;

document.getElementById("status-button-bar").innerHTML = '';
var gameOverAlert = true;
if (gameOverAlert == true); {
var gameOverAlert = false;
}
window.location.href = "https://parkingmaster.w3spaces.com/index.html?bypass-cache=1624983081";
document.getElementById("hidebuttons").innerHTML = '';
}
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
function parkinglot(draw) {
ctx.fillStyle = '#fad201';
ctx.fillRect(590, 0, 10, canvas.height);
ctx.fillRect(450, 0, 140, 10);
ctx.fillRect(450, 90, 140, 10);
ctx.fillRect(450, 180, 140, 10);
// outline
ctx.fillStyle = '#00FF00';
ctx.fillRect(450, 270, 20, 10);
ctx.fillRect(480, 270, 20, 10);
ctx.fillRect(510, 270, 20, 10);
ctx.fillRect(540, 270, 20, 10);
ctx.fillRect(570, 270, 20, 10);

ctx.fillStyle = '#00FF00';
ctx.fillRect(450, 360, 20, 10);
ctx.fillRect(480, 360, 20, 10);
ctx.fillRect(510, 360, 20, 10);
ctx.fillRect(540, 360, 20, 10);
ctx.fillRect(570, 360, 20, 10);
}
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
function cars(draw) {
ctx.fillStyle = '#000000';
ctx.fillRect(0, 20, 110,65);
ctx.fillRect(5, 78, 30,10);
ctx.fillRect(75, 78, 30,10)
ctx.fillRect(5, 17, 30,10);
ctx.fillRect(75, 17, 30,10)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code ends with:

```js
cars(draw);
parkinglot(draw);
```

So you're drawing the cars, and then the parking-lot.

Canvas draws new elements on op of existing elements, therefore your parking-lot will be placed above the car drawings.

So'll you'll probably just need to change the order of drawing:

```js
parkinglot(draw);
cars(draw);
```

---

Example were we draw a red line, and then a green one. You'll see that the last drawn line will be visible in the intersection:

```js
let c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
c.width = 200;
c.height = 200;

let x = c.getContext('2d');
x.lineWidth = 5;

// Red
x.beginPath();
x.moveTo(0, 0);
x.lineTo(200, 200);
x.strokeStyle = "#ff5500";
x.stroke();

// Green
x.beginPath();
x.moveTo(200, 0);
x.lineTo(0, 200);
x.strokeStyle = "#008000";
x.stroke();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: That was a mistake, the `cars();`  function was used to draw the car obstacles parked around the car, honest mistake, I edited the question above. Sorry!